# How to set value inside bubble in bubble charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, cocoapods, core-plot

I have a code that makes a bubble chart, but I want to the bubbles to have numbers written in them. Please can anyone advise?

Here is the sample code that returns a bubble in the form of BubbleChartDataEntry. I want the bubbles to have numbers as seen below: [image: bubble chart example photo] Currently, my code returns the graph below

[image: Actual graph]

I want to keep the x-axis

```
    func setDataCount(_ count: Int, range: UInt32) {
    let yVals1 = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BubbleChartDataEntry in
        let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(range))
        let size = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(range))
        return BubbleChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val, size: size, icon: UIImage(named: "icon"))
    }
    let yVals2 = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BubbleChartDataEntry in
        let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(range))
        let size = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(range))
        return BubbleChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val, size: size, icon: UIImage(named: "icon"))
    }
    let yVals3 = (0..<count).map { (i) -> BubbleChartDataEntry in
        let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(range))
        let size = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(range))
        return BubbleChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val, size: size)
    }
    
    let set1 = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: yVals1, label: "DS 1")
    set1.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set1.setColor(ChartColorTemplates.colorful()[0], alpha: 0.5)
    set1.drawValuesEnabled = true
    
    let set2 = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: yVals2, label: "DS 2")
    set2.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set2.iconsOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 15)
    set2.setColor(ChartColorTemplates.colorful()[1], alpha: 0.5)
    set2.drawValuesEnabled = true
    
    let set3 = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: yVals3, label: "DS 3")
    set3.setColor(ChartColorTemplates.colorful()[2], alpha: 0.5)
    set3.drawValuesEnabled = true
    
    let data = [set1, set2, set3] as BubbleChartData
    data.setDrawValues(false)
    data.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 7)!)
    data.setHighlightCircleWidth(1.5)
    data.setValueTextColor(.white)
    
    chartView.data = data
}
```

Comment: A couple of things to help clarify the question. First it seems unrelated to Realm so that tag should be removed. It also appears you're asking a question about a third party library, core-plot, so that tag should be added if that's correct. Lastly, More info about BubbleChartDataSet would be needed as I don't see where you're setting any kind of label.

Comment: Thank you. thats a fragment of the code. I want the bubble size to written inside the bubble. please are you able to help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it.

```
data.setDrawValues(true)
data.setValueTextColor(.white)
```